# window.crypto returns 352 bit key instead of 256?

Tags: javascript, encryption, window.crypto

I'm trying to encrypt some text using `window.crypto`:

```
await crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, dataArrayBuffer).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

However I get this error `AES key data must be 128 or 256 bits`. I'm using PBKDF2 to create a 256 bit key from a password and I specify a key length of `256`:

```
window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
            {
                "name": "PBKDF2",
                "salt": salt,
                "iterations": iterations,
                "hash": hash
            },
            baseKey,
            {"name": "AES-GCM", "length": 256}, //<------------
            true, 
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
            );
```

But I end up getting this key `edi5Fou4yCdSdx3DX3Org+L2XFAsVdomVgpVqUGjJ1g=` after I `exportKey` it and convert it from an `ArrayBuffer` to a `string` with a length of `44` bytes and `352` bits...

Which would explain the error, but how can I create an actual `256` bit key from `window.crypto`'s `PBKDF2`?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lyaoudc/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displayed lengths refer to the Base64 encoded key. A 32 bytes key has a Base64 encoded length of 44 bytes (352 bits) in accordance with the displayed values, which are therefore correct, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding).

The bug is that in the 2nd `importKey` (see comment *Create CryptoKey for AES-GCM from import*) the Base64 encoded key (i.e. `keyString`) is passed instead of the binary key (i.e. the `ArrayBuffer` `keyBytes`). If `keyBytes` is passed, the encryption works:

```js
function deriveAKey(password, salt, iterations, hash) {

    // First, create a PBKDF2 "key" containing the password
    window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        stringToArrayBuffer(password),
        {"name": "PBKDF2"},
        false,
        ["deriveKey"]).
    then(function(baseKey){
        // Derive a key from the password
        return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
            {
                "name": "PBKDF2",
                "salt": salt,
                "iterations": iterations,
                "hash": hash
            },
            baseKey,
            {"name": "AES-GCM", "length": 256}, // Key we want.Can be any AES algorithm ("AES-CTR", "AES-CBC", "AES-CMAC", "AES-GCM", "AES-CFB", "AES-KW", "ECDH", "DH", or "HMAC")
            true,                               // Extractable
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"]              // For new key
            );
    }).then(function(aesKey) {
        // Export it so we can display it
        return window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", aesKey);
    }).then(async function(keyBytes) {
        // Display key in Base64 format
        var keyS = arrayBufferToString(keyBytes);
        var keyB64 = btoa (keyS);
        console.log(keyB64);
        
        console.log('Key byte size: ', byteCount(keyB64));
        console.log('Key bit size: ', byteCount(keyB64) * 8);
        
        var keyString = stringToArrayBuffer(keyB64);
    
        const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));

        const algorithm = {
          name: 'AES-GCM',
          iv: iv,
        };

        //Create CryptoKey for AES-GCM from import
        const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
          'raw',//Provided key will be of type ArrayBuffer
          // keyString,
          keyBytes,                                                    // 1. Use keyBytes instead of keyString
          {
            name: "AES-GCM",
          },
          false,//Key not extractable
          ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
        );

        //Convert data to ArrayBuffer
        var data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";      // 2. Define data
        const dataArrayBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(data);

        const encryptedArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, dataArrayBuffer).catch(error => console.error(error));
        
        var ivB64 = btoa(arrayBufferToString(iv));
        console.log(ivB64);                                            // 3. Display (Base64 encoded) IV
        
        var encB64 = btoa(arrayBufferToString(encryptedArrayBuffer));
        console.log(encB64.replace(/(.{56})/g,'$1\n'));                // 4. Display (Base64 encoded) ciphertext (different for each encryption, because of random salt and IV)

    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error("Key derivation failed: " + err.message);
    });
}

//Utility functions

function stringToArrayBuffer(byteString){
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for(var i=0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = byteString.codePointAt(i);
    }
    return byteArray;
}

function  arrayBufferToString(buffer){
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var byteString = '';
    for(var i=0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
        byteString += String.fromCodePoint(byteArray[i]);
    }
    return byteString;
}

function byteCount(s) {
    return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
}

var salt = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
var iterations = 5000;
var hash = "SHA-512";
var password = "password";

deriveAKey(password, salt, iterations, hash);
```

In addition to the key, the code also displays IV and ciphertext, each Base64 encoded. The ciphertext can be verified e.g. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Base64%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Base64%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%27GCM%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27)Find_/_Replace(%7B%27option%27:%27Regex%27,%27string%27:%27Tag:%27%7D,%27%27,false,false,false,false)Remove_whitespace(true,false,true,false,false,false)From_Hex(%27Auto%27)To_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27)&input=VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZw) using the Base64 encoded key and IV.

Comment: ```btoa("A".repeat(32)).length``` => 44